# Click in table with function toggleClass

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to show a table where you have the possibility to click within the selected tr. Every time I click within this tr, the highlight activates because I used the function toggleClass. Im trying to find a way to make the user click within the "already" highlighed class without making it toggle.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr:not(:first)").click(function() {
        $(this).closest("tr").siblings().removeClass("highlighted");
        $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
    });
});
```

Update:

https://jsfiddle.net/vakcrthL/1/

Everytime the user needs to ad a copy the toggleClass hides it from the page.

Comment: can you add HTML? or a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `e.stopPropagation();` in both `.qtyplus` and `.qtyminus` `click` event handlers to prevent call of `tr` click event handler.

`e.preventDefault();` and `e.stopPropagation();` can be replaced with `return false;` at the end of handler.

Example of one handler (code not connected with event propagation is left untouched):

```
$('.qtyplus').click(function() {
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        $('input[name=' + fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
    } else {
        $('input[name=' + fieldName+']').val(0);
    }
    return false;
});
```

[Full fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/vakcrthL/2/).

Since clicking on `<input>` with value still hides the row, it makes sense to prevent hiding on its click as well:

```
$(".qty").on("click", false);
```

[Full fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/vakcrthL/3/).

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a way to close the .qtyminus and .qtyplus when the user clicks on another tr?

Comment: @MarloesL you're welcome. Yes, there is. I have modified code: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vakcrthL/4/). It's worth to notice that I have deleted some your code which is not necessary anymore: look at code attentively.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to do that!

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
$("tr:not(:first)").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("highlighted").siblings().removeClass("highlighted");
});
```

Because you are clicking on `tr` itself so you don't need to use `.closest()` method **`$(this)` is actually your current `tr` which is been clicked**. and You can use `addClass()` on the current one clicked and remove the class from the siblings of the clicked `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr:not(:first)").click(function() {
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("highlighted");
        $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can some the the click event from propagating trough the parent elements with event.stopPropagation() in jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr:not(:first)").click(function() {
        $(this).closest("tr").siblings().removeClass("highlighted");
        $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
    });
    $("tr:not(:first)").children().click(function(event) {
           event.stopPropagation();                
           //the rest of your click
    })
});
```